# Escalate case using business hours

Tags: process-builder, businesshours

We are using process builder to escalate a case and send email notifications to specific queues. The escalation works using scheduled actions...i.e. after 1 hour send email, after 2 send another email to another queue, after 3 hours send another email to another queue. This works fine.

However, we have business hours defined and is there a way for the scheduled actions in process builder to take into account the business hours?

Comment: Why not use Escalation Rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there's an idea to use [Business Hours in Process Builder](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lE4YQAU). For now, consider using an [Escalation Rule](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rules_escalation_create.htm&type=5), which can use business hours, and is capable of emailing users/queues and assigning records to new owners, if necessary.

Comment: thanks for the response. I thought case escalation rules do not use business hours? I was mistaken. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @Dman100 yes, each rule entry can use business hours.